# Ensure function signature type depending on value of other parameter

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a function that verifies that a property has a generic type and returns its value.

```js
// tslint:disable-next-line no-any -> must be any, or typescript can't infer the return value
function ensureProperty<T>(obj: object, propertyName: string, guard: (obj: any | undefined) => obj is T): T {
    const val = obj[propertyName];
    if (!guard(val)) {
        throw new Error(propertyName);
    }
    return val;
}
```

Which works great, but I'm wondering if there is a way to tell typescript that the object `obj` should be of a type that has a property with the specified name.

```js
const obj = { example: ""};
ensureProperty(obj, "notexisting", Guard.isString); // this should result in a type error
ensureProperty(obj, "example", Guard.isString); // this should work
```

I was thinking about something like: (I know this can't work, I'm just thinking it might clarify my intent...)

```js
function ensureProperty<T>(obj: {[key == propertyName]: T|undefined}, propertyName: string, ...
```

But I am afraid there is no such language construct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
function ensureProperty<T, K>(obj: K, propertyName: keyof K, guard: (obj: any | undefined) => obj is T): T {
    const val = obj[propertyName];
    if (!guard(val)) {
        throw new Error(propertyName.toString());
    }
    return val;
}
```

which results in

```
const obj = { example: ""};
ensureProperty(obj, "notexisting", Guard.isString); // Argument of type '"notexisting"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"example"'.
ensureProperty(obj, "example", Guard.isString); // OK
```

Notice that now `propertyName` can't be passed directly to the `Error` constructor, so we have to convert it to a string first.

Comment: No way to limit the type of the propertyName to string?

Comment: `propertyName: keyof K & string`